# reload tableView in last method run

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotification

I have method that get notification as I download one image. I can download a lot of objects and I want to update tableView then I have last notification of downloaded image. How the best way to accomplish it?

```
- (void)requestDownloadAvatarWithImageString:(NSString *)imageString completion:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *image, NSError *error))completion __attribute__((nonnull(2)))
{
NSParameterAssert(completion);

NSString *urlString = imageString;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    completion(operation, responseObject, nil);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    DDLogError(@"FAIL download image: %@",error);
}];

[requestOperation start];
}
```

Comment: By calling `[tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: @ nhgrif , I need to call only with last notification. For ex[ample in 5 sec I have 100 notifications, I need last

Comment: Then keep track of how many you're waiting for.  Better would probably be to reload the cell for which the download just completed (reload an individual cell)

Comment: How then I can detect that I will have notification rather then it was last?

Comment: By including a lot more code.  There's a million different ways.

Comment: yep, I need help to find one of this solutions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(NUMBER_OF_RETURNED_OBJECTS);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    for (i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_RETURNED_OBJECTS; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            fetchObject(i); // it's specific to your application

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}   

[your_table_view reloadData];
```

or simply get all image paths in an array then download them with SDWebImage

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];


NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString, imageArray[indexPath.row]];

[cell.cell_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

}
```

Comment: make all downloads asynchronously.

Comment: make all download asynchronously. dispatch_semaphore_wait waits until all of them finished

Comment: I need to run it from download method in complete block? if I do not know NUMBER_OF_RETURNED_OBJECTS how nan I work with it?

Comment: How do you download them? Could you send some piece of code?

Comment: I would download image paths as an array and place them to table. Then I would load the images with SDWebImage in TableView's data source method.

Comment: I added download method in my post

Comment: is imageString belong only one image?

Comment: Yes. I use this method to download images for parts of app. Basically I want to reload tableView then I received  last notification of downloaded image

Comment: Does this function only return one image?

Comment: Yes, it did, responseObject is one image

Comment: How do you know how many photos should you fetch?

Comment: I parse web response and have as much images as links it have

Comment: If you already know the number of photos you should know the which one is the last one.

Comment: I do not know number of photos.

Comment: You said "I parse web response and have as much images as links it have " so you know the image links. Add them all to an array then load them with SDWebImage in  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: [cell.cell_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: NO no no, I can not do it my data model. I solve it. I add NSInteger in download class and increase it then I have download and decrease it then it finished. Then check for this number. IF it 0 - I reload tableView